# Error Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope when using $injector to inject $scope into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, scope, angularjs-injector

When using DI in this fashion:

```
var MainController = function MainController($scope) {
  //use $scope here
};
MainController.$inject = ["$scope"];
```

It, work but, when it's used like this:

```
var MainController = function MainController($injector) {
  var $scope = $injector.get("$scope");
};
MainController.$inject = ["$injector"];
```

This will result in error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jVVyou7m0GLKpfmIbSCf?p=preview) with an example that showcases the error, check the comments for an alternative to see that only the scope not custom services are affected by this.
I found this [Angular bug](https://github.com/angular/router/issues/192) where they talk about the controller being instantiated before the child $scope is being created as [Tomer Avni](https://github.com/TomerAvni) answered, so:

1. why the first way of injecting `$scope` work while the second doesn't?
2. And is there a way to use the second method of Dependency injection 
   with `$injector` to inject `$scope`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've replied to you on gitter, but answering here as well as it may help other who have the same issue.

---

When you give Angular a function to call that has values that will be derived from dependency injection (e.g. a service, a controller, etc.), Angular will:

- Look for an `.$inject` property on the function object which should be an array of dependency names as strings (e.g. `['$scope']`).
- If `$inject` is undefined, it will use the parameters of the function definition (which works in most cases, unless you minify your code and the names get mangled).

So, in a nutshell, it will look up the names you have specified in the DI container.

`$scope` **doesn't exist in the DI container**, only `$rootScope` does. So, if you're accessing the injector directly and asking for an instance of `$scope`, you'll get the injection error you've seen here.

In the example where it worked, you're not accessing the injector directly but instead relying on Angular working out how to create your controller. That's a subtle difference, but in this case an important one. Within Angular, when creating the controller instance it will resolve `$scope` to the result of calling `$rootScope.$new()` (i.e. what you would do when manually instantiating the controller in a unit test).

I hope that explains why your example didn't work.

As for the second question, you could manually get a scope instance by doing something like:

`var $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();`

But now we're starting to go down a pretty murky path... It's quite atypical to inject the `$injector` directly. I'd avoid that if you can. Is there a reason you need to do this?

Comment: I'm injecting the `$injector` directly because in my app I have a lot of dependencies so the function arguments gets really long, so by injecting the `$injector` I can make it vertical, I guess I'll just be injecting the `$scope` and the `$injector` now.

Comment: Ok, I've had similar situations and whilst usually it's a sign you need to start refactoring, if you can't get around it you can always put your controller params on new lines:


`
function MyController(
  someParam,
  anotherParam
) {
}
`

Comment: ..so multiline code snippets don't work that well in comments :)